# Books with Glossaries

Tags: textbooks, graduate-education, reference-books

I am seeking example math books that have a glossary.
I would especially be interested in an example that has a list of symbols,
a glossary, and an index.

I am working on a book (aimed at graduate students and researchers)
and I'm trying to decide if all three (symbols, glossary, index)
make sense. I've used all three but not in the same book, and at lower educational levels.

Comment: IIT-JAM book might help :)

Comment: I don't know that I have ever come across a mathematics text with a glossary.  Indices of notation and terms are quite useful, but the idea is that you look up a symbol or term in the appropriate index, and the "glossary entry" is a definition in the text.  At least, that is how nearly every mathematics text I've ever read does things.  A glossary seems redundant.

Comment: This book, Berger, M. (2003). *A panoramic view of Riemannian geometry*, has a 6-page alphabetized "List of Notation." I may follow this.

Comment: @Raciquel: "if the glossary provided definitions of prerequisite material not included in the text." Good point!